# random html on response.write

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

hello guys I'm working on an intership where they use ASP to code. Coming from PHP, well I am somewhat confused. I have a form that gets sent with JQuery using $.post().

```
 $.post("sendmail.asp",{
       fname:$("#fName").val(),
       lname:$('#lName').val(),
       addy1:$('#addy1').val(),
       addy2:$('#addy2').val(),
       city:$('#city').val(),
       zip:$('#zip').val(),
       state:$('#state').val(),
       ephone:$('ephone').val(),
       dphone:$('dphone').val(),
       email:$('#email').val(),
       comm:$('comm').val()
       },function(e){
            alert("Server response: "+e)
       })
```

I call a script sendmail.asp that uses a class to send mail and after the mail gets sent I do `response.write("email sent")` but I get

```
<random HTML that seems to be generated from bootstrap>
email sent
```

All I want as response is `email sent`.I have no idea what am I doing wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please clean up your code to make it easier to read.

Comment: Can you please take care to format your code correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there an include directive in your sendmail.asp script?

```
<!--#include virtual="somefilename"-->
```

Easy to miss as it looks like a comment.

Comment: hard to tell what exactly is wrong without seeing the ASP script.

Comment: Sorry I did not put all the the code. But you're right there is a header.asp that I was told to use because it has a global class that these people use to send mail. This header.asp was setting a page so I just changed the include to just the class i needed and BOOM done.

Answer (score 2):

Try `response.Clear` before `response.write`